# Xamarin how to set diferent row color in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin

I'm trying to create a listView in Xamarin where some elements in rows will be different depending on a value in an object.
For example. Model of note:

```
public class Note
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
<Label Text="{Binding Content}" TextColor="#503026" />
<Button BackgroundColor="#000" />
```

And I wish to have button `BackgroundColor` depending on `Active` field. If `Active` is `false` then `BackgroundColor` is set to red. If `true` then `BackgroundColor` is set to green.

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make a value converter to let you bind color to boolean:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool b = ((bool)value);
            return b ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, import the converter into your xaml file:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
```

Add it to your page's resource dictionary:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <local:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="boolToColorConverter"/>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then you can use it in your binding:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
<Label Text="{Binding Content}" TextColor="#503026" />
<Button BackgroundColor="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource boolToColorConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Works great. P.S. Should be a coma after Binding property in BackgroundColor.